# DRY Problem with Rspec how can i fix it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, dry

i am new in Ruby and Rspec. I am writing my first RSpec test and i think that my code is not very well. But i don't know how i can make it better.

In this file i will check my Address class. The first_name and last_name are the same but i have two big blocks for it. How can i refactor my code? And what is a good way to check RegExp.

Thank you.

```
specify { Factory.build(:address).should be_valid }


  ### first_name ###

  it "should be invalid without an first_name" do
    Factory.build(:address, :first_name => nil).should_not be_valid
  end


  context "first_name" do

    it "should be invalid with more than 20 chars" do
      Factory.build(:address, :first_name => "#{'b'*21}").should_not be_valid
    end

    it "should be invalid with less than 3 chars" do
      Factory.build(:address, :first_name => "ll").should_not be_valid
    end

    it "should be valid with an valid first_name" do      
       valid_names.each do |name|
        Factory.build(:address, :first_name => name).should be_valid
       end
    end

    it "should be invalid with an invalid first_name" do
      invalid_names.each do |name|
        Factory.build(:address, :first_name => name).should_not be_valid
      end
    end    
  end


  ### last_name ###

  it "should be invalid without an last_name" do
    Factory.build(:address, :last_name => nil).should_not be_valid
  end

  context "last_name" do
    it "should be invalid with more than 20 chars" do
      Factory.build(:address, :last_name => "#{'b'*21}").should_not be_valid
    end

    it "should be invalid with less than 3 chars" do
      Factory.build(:address, :last_name => "ll").should_not be_valid
    end

    it "should be valid with an valid last_name" do      
       valid_names.each do |name|
        Factory.build(:address, :last_name => name).should be_valid
       end
    end

    it "should be invalid with an invalid last_name" do
      invalid_names.each do |name|
        Factory.build(:address, :last_name => name).should_not be_valid
      end
    end    
  end
 def valid_names    
    ["Kai","Ülück's","Schmeißtzs","Rald","Dr. Franzen","rolfes","Lars Michael","Öcück","Mark-Anthony"] 
  end

  def invalid_names    
    ["-#+*32","         ","a& &lkdf","_-_.l##df"," aaadsa","M€lzer"]
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

so here's the way I sometimes do this kind of thing:

```
describe Address do
  describe "validations" do
    before do
      @address = Factory(:address)
    end
    describe "#first_name" do
      #prove that your factory is correct
      it "should be valid" do
        @address.should be_valid
      end
      it "should be less than 20 chars" do
        @address.name = "0" * 20
        @address.should_not be_valid
      end
      it "should be more than 3 chars" do
        @address.name = "000"
        @address.should_not be_valid
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I would use the subject method for this, like its done here: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/blob/master/features/expectations/attribute_of_subject.feature

Answer (score 1):

Remember that your tests don't need to be really DRY. Don't sacrifice readability for it.

Think of your specs as examples: which examples should be valid and which shouldn't? That's also the clue to testing regexes: provide some examples that pass and some that don't.

For validations, I made some custom matchers, which can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/657073). Example:

```
describe Address do
  it { should deny(:last_name).to_be(nil, "", "1", "br", "a& &lkdf","_-_.l##df", "lzer") }
  it { should allow(:last_name).to_be("Kai","Ülück's","Schmeißtzs","Rald","Dr. Franzen","rolfes","Lars Michael","Öcück","Mark-Anthony") }
end
```